# Spring Autowiring not working (Dependency Injection)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

**EDIT: I just found that my question is basically what is explained [here](http://koenserneels.blogspot.de/2012/11/javafx-2-with-spring.html). So I will now first try to get it working with the information I can find there.**

I'm doing my first steps with the Spring Framework, resp. its autowiring functionality. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/index.htm) but it seems I have missed something. I have successfully added all spring jars to my project and defined a configuration ("springbeans.xml") in my src folder as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="myC" class="some.package.C"></bean>

</beans>
```

In my application's main method, I'm initializing the configuration:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springbeans.xml");
```

Note that I'm just creating an anonymous reference to trigger the initialization, but not storing it to any variable, because I'm not trying to retrieve my instance via `context.getBean("myC")` (which works, by the way!). But as I understood it should be enough to just trigger the initialization of everything?

So then, I have this class "C" in the package `some.package` that I want to autowire. The class provides one public constructor, which has no parameters. I have **not** annotated this class in any way, and maybe that's the problem. However I had tried to annotate it as `@Service` or `@Component`, but it didn't solve the problem. But to be honest I didn't really understand when to use these annotations and what they mean.

Anyway, then I have some other class where I try to autowire my C instance:

```
...
@Autowired
private C c;
```

and some method in that class that uses the c variable. But when that method gets executed, I get a NullPointerException, so obviously the Autowiring didn't work.

What did I do wrong?

**edit:** So as was explained to me, my problem is that the class where I am using the autowiring in must be a bean too and initialized by spring too. But here's the problem with that: This class is actually a JavaFX controller class in my case. I don't instantiate it, JavaFX does it internally. Does it mean I cannot use autowiring there?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I have found a solution how to use Spring with JavaFX controllers. The key is to load the FXML with a spring-managed loader:

```
public class SpringFxmlLoader {

    private static final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springbeans.xml");

    public static Parent load(String url) {
        try (InputStream fxmlStream = SpringFxmlLoader.class
                .getResourceAsStream(url)) {
            System.err.println(SpringFxmlLoader.class
                    .getResourceAsStream(url));
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setControllerFactory(clazz -> applicationContext.getBean(clazz));
            return loader.load(fxmlStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I define my controller as a bean in my spring configuration, and also define my autowiring target as a bean, I can successfully autowire the target class in my FX controller class.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired
private C myC;
You have to rename your object to your id name

Answer (score 0):

When spring creates beans on your behalf, you need to tell it if your bean id and instance reference name are different.

What you want to achieve can be achieved in three ways.

1. Change your xml config to match bean id with reference name

> bean id="c" class="some.package.C"

2. Change your instance reference name to make it same as bean id
   @Autowired

> private C myC;

3. Provide Qualifier to indicate your autowiring

> @Autowire 
>   @Qualifier("myC") 
>   private C c;

Comment: I tried the first option to name the autowired variable the same as the bean id, but I still get the same error

Comment: can you check if you are creating object of the class(which contains @Autowire private C c;) using new keyword? if you are doing that, spring can not inject c into that(user created object) make sure Spring is creating those beans for you

Comment: ah, so the class that contains the autowired must be a bean too? So then I guess I have a problem, because what I didn't tell you so far is that I'm using this in a JavaFX application, and the class where I want to have something autowired is a FX controller. This class gets created by JavaFX internally. Anyone knows how I can use autowiring in such case?

Comment: Not me! please mention those things too in your question.